Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Statement::__construct(): Argument #1 ($stmt) must be of type PDOStatement, null given
I am getting a very unexpected and unusual error that is kinda hard to trace. I'm thinking this might be actually covering some other, maybe driver level issue?
This is Postgres on gcloud, PHP-fpm POD, side effect is that after couple of occurrences POD becomes unresponsive, after it is restarted everything comes back to life. The issue does not affect ALL calls to this piece of code, it occurs from time to time, multiple times in a row on f.e. one POD while on other everything works ok.
Any suggestions what might be the cause? I'm in the dark right now and google is not helpfull.
Uncaught Error: Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Statement::__construct(): Argument #1 ($stmt) must be of type
PDOStatement, null given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/PDO/Connection.php
on line 62 {"exception":"[object] (TypeError(code: 0): Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDO\\Statement::__construct()
:Argument #1 ($stmt) must be of type PDOStatement, null given, called in
/var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/PDO/Connection.php on line 62 at
/var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/PDO/Statement.php:22

